# Reading S3 files in a for loop in a Spark application

Tags: apache-spark

Is it ill-advised to read files in a for-loop in a Spark program? Like so

```
for (each file in S3 bucket)
  RDD <- file
  transform
  action
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to load files in a loop or are you trying to load all files in the bucket to a RDD?

Comment: My objective is to process all files in the bucket and do it one at a time, but all in the same application run

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're really looking for is actually the *sc.wholeTextFile* API :

```
  /**
   * Read a directory of text files from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any
   * Hadoop-supported file system URI. Each file is read as a single record and returned in a
   * key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.
   *
   * <p> For example, if you have the following files:
   * {{{
   *   hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-00000
   *   hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-00001
   *   ...
   *   hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-nnnnn
   * }}}
   *
   * Do `val rdd = sparkContext.wholeTextFile("hdfs://a-hdfs-path")`,
   *
   * <p> then `rdd` contains
   * {{{
   *   (a-hdfs-path/part-00000, its content)
   *   (a-hdfs-path/part-00001, its content)
   *   ...
   *   (a-hdfs-path/part-nnnnn, its content)
   * }}}
   *
   * @note Small files are preferred, large file is also allowable, but may cause bad performance.
   *
   * @param minPartitions A suggestion value of the minimal splitting number for input data.
   */
  def wholeTextFiles(path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions):
```

Available on your SparkContext, then you can just use a wildcard (glob-like) like that :

```
sc.wholeTextFile("s3://my-directory/2015*/user-134/*")
```

Regards,

Olivier.